# MS Flow which send an email containing all the activities that has been done on a list or library from the compliance center audit logs

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, ms-flow, compliance-center

Inside Office 365 compliance center we can generate reports as follow:-

[image]

But i am not sure if i can automate this process using Power automate ? for example to create a power automate flow >> which will integrate with the compliance center audit's api or using built-in actions and generate an email containing all the activities that has been done on a list or library and send it on daily/weekly basis ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Regards